# Facebook Increasingly Grouping News Feed Stories from Apps and Sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

From my rails app I don't want to be grouped all these Facebook Newfeed as given in the expamle url.

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/05/17/facebook-increasingly-grouping-news-feed-stories-from-apps-and-sites/

Any idea How I can stop above thing.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2):

First off, that article is over 18 months old.

Secondly, there's no way for your app to 'game' the news feed algorithm in the way you're describing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having another query now. I passed action_links as the parameter with text and url. When I post First time is does appear on the facebook newsfeed but from the second post it grouped both posts and action_links content goes out. I dont understand why this is happing. I am using facebooker plugin to publish.